# Detect BPM of Mp3

Tags: objective-c, visual-c++

I want to know if there is a way in c++ or objective-c to get the BPM of a Mp3 file.

i found until now a source code for stuff that do it on wav files and not on mp3 file,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BPM (or beat) detection is a complicated algorithm that involves analyzing the sound stream in different ways. For this to happen, at least internally the MP3 must be decoded. Typically these are things you'd actually write *in* a language such as but not limited to C++ or Objective-C.

There are many libraries / pieces of code available that solve both problems, or in the case of beat detection: take a shot at it.

Answer (score 1):

There's certainly no way to do BPM detection in the core C++ or Objective-C languages. You need to write the functionality yourself or take advantage of one of the [many libraries](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MP3%20BPM%20detection%20library%20C%2B%2B) that provide it.

If you can't find a suitable library that supports MP3 directly then you're going to have to decode to PCM first.